# Which tools are available to effectively parse & scrape this HTML?

Tags: html, parsing

I have about 2000 documents from which I'm trying to pull metadata. Right now, the metadata is hardcoded as content at the top of the document.

Some givens: 
Each page is generated with a `<script>...</script>` at the head, and I no longer need to capture data starting at the first instance of `<p style=...` so I can use those tags as "start" and "end" markers.

I don't need tags, just the text, and I'd prefer a delimited text output, 9 columns, each column representing the data. (e.g., columns would be `Desc, RefNum, Replaces, SpecCond, States, How, When, Owner, ChgDate` and each line would represent a single document's data--one line per HTML document).

I'm also trying to automate this as much as possible, so I'd like a tool that will crawl a path and its subdirectories looking for *.html and scraping the content.

I'm not really sure where to start. Thoughts?

```
</script>
<!--                        -->
<!--  BEGIN CAPTURE HERE    --> 
<!--                        -->
<h1>Additional Deposit Warning</h1>
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">Description: Additional Deposit</font></p>        
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">Reference Number: 897</font></p>
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">Replaces Letter: CIBS 417</font></p>
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">Special Conditions: NA</font></p>
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">States Applicable: WI, MI</font></p>
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">How Generated: User Selects In CSS</font></p>
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">When Generated: Additional deposit may be needed</font></p>
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">Owner: Credit - Deposits</font></p>
<p class="Plain_Text"><font style="font-family:'Arial';">Last change letter: March 27, 2003</font></p>
<!--                        -->
<!--  END CAPTURE HERE      --> 
<!--                        -->
<p style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0">&#160;</p>
<p><font style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:12pt;">#Mdate</font></p>
<p><font style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:12pt;"><br />
```

Comment: What programming language? Any framework(s)?

Comment: Sounds like a problem for [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL - No specific programming language or frameworks, hever, see my comment below. 

I'm in that unique position of working in a user area, where even though I know what I'm doing, I don't get access to a shell account. :\   </grumble>

Comment: @Neil - yes it certainly does sound like awk would fit the bill. 

See my additional note to MДΓΓ БДLL, too.

Comment: Well that certainly does cramp your style.  That means your next best alternative is to write a javascript program which does this for you, though it's probably not your best solution if accuracy is important, since browsers tend to omit styles it thinks are useless, assuming you're working with html and not a dynamic web page.

Comment: Cramp is an understatement...that being said, I'm playing with gawk right now. But I may end up with java or javascript. I'm working with static HTML, dynamically created by RoboHelp, so that helps. I suspect I'm on the right-est track for what I've got to work with. Thanks for the input and tip about awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using javascript. It took a few rewrites to account for anomalous data, but all in all it worked well.